# Opening Firebug stops javascript from running

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

I have noticed with the latest level of firefox(33.1)/firebug (2.0.6), my Javascript just stops.

The console doesn't report any errors, there is no sign of any problems.  Just when I click on clickable items, there is no action.  By closing firebug, the Javascript works again.

This does not happen for Chrome(open with Development tools) or Opera (open with Dragonfly).  I have tried a couple of different websites with the same results.

Is this a firebug bug?  Or am I missing a setting somewhere?

I have the following other plug-ins with firefox: fireQuery (1.41), HTML Validator (0.9.5.8) Pocket (3.0.5) View source Char (3.05)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently, this is related to the combination of Firefox v. 33.1, in combination with fireQuery v. 1.41.  There is more on this issue [here](http://discuss.binaryage.com/t/firequery-breaks-js-in-firefox-33/2412).

This is a bug, with the interaction between fireQuery and Firefox.

This became an issue when Firefox went from v. 32 to v. 33.

The only **solution** is to disable fireQuery and restart Firefox. Or, debug with Chrome, Safari, Opera or even (gasp) Internet Explorer.

Comment: same error with firefox 35.0.1, firebug 2.0.7 and firequery 1.4.1 under osx. just disable or remove firequery to solve this issue!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, after deactivating FireQuery JS + FireBug worked again. I hope a FireQuery update comes soon, was an very nice plugin...

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for answering! I suggest you try to edit this answer with some additional info. And you should remove the last sentence as it doesn't help answer the question. Thanks! (You risk having this answer deleted if it's not improved).